# Why do I suddenly have #'s around my python file?

Tags: python, emacs

I'm currently using emacs to write python files but every so often when I open my file folder I find that I have copies of the file but with #'s around them. For example, I'm working on a file called twist.py. For some reason I now appear to have something called #twist.py#, even though I never made a file with this name.

What does this mean and why does it happen?

Comment: Emacs temporary backup files. They disappear when you close emacs. You can turn creation of those files in emacs off if you want.

Answer (score 3):

`#filename#` files are auto-save files; effectively temporary backup files. Your `#twist.py#` file is likely there because you've been idle (not typing) for 30 seconds since you last saved `twist.py`, or you've typed 300 characters since your last save. (These are the defaults; the options are configurable with `auto-save-timeout` and `auto-save-interval`, respectively.) You can read more about this behaviour in [the documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Auto-Save-Control.html).

If you don't like these files for whatever reason, they should disappear when you save the file manually. You can disable them entirely with:

```el
(setq auto-save-default nil)
```

If you'd instead like them to be out of the way in the `tmp` directory, [this blog post](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/05/09/keep-backup-and-auto-save-files-out-of-the-way/) suggests an addition to `.emacs`:

```el
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
      `((".*" ,temporary-file-directory t)))
```